# How to upload file into target directory with curl?

Tags: php, curl

There is a file `"/home/test.mp4"`  in my local machine,

I want to upload it into `/var/www/ok.mp4` (the name changed when uploaded it). All the source file and target file are in the local machine.

How to fix my partial code ,to add something or to change something ?

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); 
curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Think to Ram Sharma, the code was changed as the following:

```
<?php
$request = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1/');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' => '@' . realpath('/home/test.mp4')
    ));
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);
// close the session
curl_close($request);
?>
```

An error message occur:

It works!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

I have test with ftp_put,code1 works fine.

code1:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $host = 'xxxx';
    $usr = 'yyyy';
    $pwd = 'zzzz';
    $src = 'd:/upload.sql';
    $ftp_path = '/public_html/';
    $des = 'upload_ftp_put.sql';
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");
    ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path.$des, $src, FTP_ASCII); 
    print($upload);
?>
```

The file `d:/upload.sql` in my local pc can be uploaded into  `my_ftp_ip/public_html/upload_ftp_put.sql` with code1.
Now i rewite it with curl into code2.

code2:

```
<?php
  set_time_limit(0);
  $ch = curl_init();
  $host = 'xxxx';
  $usr = 'yyyy';
  $pwd = 'zzzz';
  $src = 'd:/upload.sql';
  $ftp_path = '/public_html';
  $dest = 'upload_curl.sql';
  $fp = fopen($src, 'r');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://user:pwd@host/'.$ftp_path .'/'. $dest);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($src));
  curl_exec ($ch);
  $error_no = curl_errno($ch);
  print($error_no);
  curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

The error info output is 6 .Why can't upload my local file into the ftp with curl?How to fix it?

Comment: If it's on the local filesystem already, why not just [`copy($src, $dest)`](http://php.net/copy)?

Comment: Why would `/home/` be accessible per HTTP anyway? And what was the `_POSTFIELDS` supposed to do?

Comment: Now i have no vps to test the code,the assumption all source and target file in local machine can be changed when you give me the right code.

Comment: You'll need a file hosted at http://127.0.0.1 with a server-side language that can take the posted field/file and put it on the local filesystem.

Comment: Why does this question now have a bounty? Is the given answer to use copy() not sufficient? Why not? What are you looking for?

Comment: what about if i have vps to do some job?

Comment: You haven’t described the problem clearly. What is it that you want to achieve? Why do you think cURL is the right tool, or that it is able to perform the task at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a low level error.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://$usr:$pwd@$host$ftp_path/$dest");
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php):

```
copy('/home/test.mp4', '/var/www/ok.mp4');
```

It does not make sense to run the file through the network stack (which is what cURL does), on any protocol (HTTP, FTP, …), when the manipulation can be done locally, through the file system. Using network is more complicated and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this and I feel instead of server directory path it would be http url.

```
// initialise the curl request
$request = curl_init('http://example.com/');
// send a file
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' => '@' . realpath('test.txt')
    ));

// output the response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);
// close the session
curl_close($request);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code might help you:

```
<?php
    $rCURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
    curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $aData = curl_exec($rCURL);
    curl_close($rCURL);
    file_put_contents('bla.jpeg', $aData);
    //  file_put_contents('my_folder/bla.jpeg', $aData); /*You can use this too*/
```

Comment: I want to put something into a url from local directory,not to download a url into my directory!

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the MIME type of the file sent like this

```
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
       'file' => '@' . realpath('/home/test.mp4') . ';type=video/mp4'
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is for the client side. If you want to upload a file using HTTP, you HTTP server must be able to handle this upload request and save the file where you want. The “error message” is probably the server’s default web page.

Sample server-side code in PHP, for your reference:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES) {
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmpname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmpname,'/var/www/ok.mp4')) {
        print_r('ok');
    } else {
        print_r('failure');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```sh
curl -X POST -F "image=@test.mp4" http://example.com/
```

You will also need a page that can process this request (POST)